# What I should use to create an Activity like this?

Tags: android

My Activity will have a ViewPager on the top and a Scroller below it. You can scroll the Scroller up to read the content in it and you can also slide the Viewpager to make the Scroller scroll immediately to the section in it.

It will be like this:

[image]

Then if you slide Viewpager to Section B,it will be like this:

[image]

Currently what I just know is to use Viewpager and Scroller to do this. What I don't know is:

**1/ *How can I make the Scroller scroll immediately to the section chosen in Viewpager?***

**2/ *How can detect (for example Section B in the Scroller) touch the Viewpager when I'm sliding up, and change the Viewpager to Section B?***